# How to add local variable inside mouseclick event?

Tags: java, swing, mouseevent, jtextfield, mouseclick-event

Here I want to call `addComponents(i)`, but it says `i` is undefined inside the mouseClicked event function.

Exact error:

> local variables referenced from an inner class must be final or effectively final

Here is my code:

```
int i =0;
for (dvc:devicelist) {
    fields[i] = new JTextField("");
    fields[i].setEditable(false);
    fields[i].addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
            addComponents(i);
        }
    });i++;
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [local variables referenced from an inner class must be final or effectively final](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32707583/local-variables-referenced-from-an-inner-class-must-be-final-or-effectively-fina)

Comment: That answer isn't great because it doesn't address the OPs use case.  I added another answer besides the accepted one to explain a bit further how the OP might proceed.

Comment: If you are wedded to the `for(dvc : devicelist)` loop, think about changing `fields` to a `List` and just `append()` the new textfield.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assign value of `i` to a local final variable like

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    fields[i] = new JTextField("");
    fields[i].setEditable(false);
final int j=i;
    fields[i].addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
            addComponents(j);
        }
    });
}
```